# High Memory usage (before computer restart) on windows 10 -previously solved now reoccurring

Tags: windows-10, memory, reboot

When I turn on my PC (Windows 10, 16GB RAM) after having been shut down (usually overnight), the RAM usage is unusually high. As a little background, within the last couple weeks I had an issue where the memory usage would go to 99% at random times without many programs running, making the computer slow and unusable. After checking for high memory usage problems others had encountered I disabled NDU, superfetch and tried a couple other fixes.

After trying those fixes the 99% memory issue went away but now when I turn on the computer the memory usage is immediately about 65%+ with nothing running, 85%+ if I run a couple programs. The computer behaves sluggishly during these states. When I restart the PC in this state, it will just be stuck on the "restarting" screen until I physically turn it off, after which point when I turn it on again the RAM usage is back to normal (until the next day when I turn on from overnight shutdown and have to repeat the entire process).

There seem to be many people experiencing high memory issues with Windows 10, but I can't find anything quite like this and am not sure if it's a memory leak or some other issue. Any help would be much appreciated.

Task Manager -> Processes (on startup after overnight shutdown):
[image: task manager- processes (on startup after overnight shutdown)]

Task Manager -> Performance (on startup after overnight shutdown):
[image: task manager- performance(on startup after overnight shutdown)]

Task Manager after failed restart/manual shutdown:
[image: task manager after failed restart/manual shutdown]

***Update: the problem went away for a couple days after running eset antivirus scan/clean, but has now reoccurred. Here is the task manager with details shown, in addition I've included a screenshot from RAMMap.
[task manager-details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTezn.png)
[RAMMap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytTDM.png)

Comment: This is strange, seems there's some application hiding from the task manager that's eating up your RAM, my guess is you have some kind of virus mate. (Although admittedly, maybe windows 10 itself is the virus... considering all the issues that plague it and updates that can unpredictably break various things...) Try doing a virus scan with malwarebytes or avira.

Comment: Also suggest, as well as Malwarebytes & Avirs, you try https://www.eset.com/us/home/free-trial/ which has found quite a few things Malwarebytes missed.

Comment: I've already run scans with Windows Defender and Malwarebytes and nothing came up. Does the fact that the computer is fine after the restart/manual shutdown make a virus less likely and more likely something is going on with windows?

Comment: Why don't you sort the *Details* in Task Manger by CPU usage (click on header to do so)? Then you might find what's eating up processor time.

Comment: The problem went away for a couple days after running ESET, but now has reoccurred. I've added the details tab of task manager to the original post.

Comment: You say you "had issues" but you don't tell us what issues you had. Were programs crashing or terminating? Did you get error messages? Was the system slow?

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer, I meant that the 99% memory usage was the initial issue and I'll update my description. The system was operating slowly when the memory usage went to 99%, but no other problems were occurring in conjunction with this.

Answer (score -1):

I am no expert but I had this problem and found that the issue is that because windows 10 has fast boot enabled by default it caches things when you use the shutdown option and the cpu cycle doesn't reset, and the uptime in task manager never resets.  My memory usage was at 99% and after about 9 days of uptime.  I generally use the shutdown option before bed. 
After a restart, it was at about 25 to 30%. Hope this helps!